# Dúvida sobre o require_once para várias classes

Tags: php, require

Tem alguma forma de fazer require de várias classes usando apenas um require_once? Eu acredito que não então estava fazendo uma função e surgiu outra dúvida, o func_get_args retorna uma array?

Comment: Sim, retorna um array contendo uma lista de argumentos da função

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o teste aqui e deu certo.

Função:

```
function multipleRequire(){
$archives = func_get_args();
$c = func_num_args();

for ($i = 0;$i<$c;$i++){
    $name = ($archives[$i] . ".php");
    require_once("$name");
}
```

}